# Database results by month and year

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I have a Joomla 3.1 site that is going to show reports about contributions made. The reports should be divided into groups by month and year. I have a code that pulls data from database but cannot make it put each month into a separate `<div>` and each year into a parent `<div>` to its months. How is it done? Here is my code.

```
<?php 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select(array($db->quoteName('contribution_date'), $db->quoteName('contribution_amount'), $db->quoteName('source')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('contribution'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
?>

<table class='financial-reports'><th>aaa</th><th>bbb</th><th>ccc</th>
<?php
foreach ( $results as $result) {
   echo '<tr>' . '<td class="fin-rep-date">' . JFactory::getDate($result->contribution_date)->format('d M, Y') . '</td>' . 
                 '<td class="fin-rep-sum">' . $result->contribution_amount . ' ' .'руб.' . '</td>' . 
                 '<td class="fin-rep-source">' . $result->source . '</td>' . '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: I Garik, check my solution, i Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easies way would be convert results into multi-dimensional array like this:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $resultsArray[JFactory::getDate($result->contribution_date)->format('Y')][JFactory::getDate($result->contribution_date)->format('M')][] = $result;
}
```

And then you can use it like that:

```
<?php foreach ($resultsArray as $year) : ?>
   <div>
      <?php foreach ($year as $month) : ?>
        <div>
           <?php foreach ($month as $item) : ?> 
             <div>YOUR OUTPUT <?php echo $item->contribution_date; ?></div>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am afraid I am not good at php, I put your code but get no results at all except the YOUR OUTPUT string. I cannot catch the idea what the code is doing. Thanks again

Comment: I've edited code, so it should work now.
The idea is to put results into array (example $resultsArray[2013][11]) so you can access all data in forech. Lets say you spin foreach results as year (you get results grouped by year, 2012, 2013), then you spin all results by month, and then by result.

Comment: Thanks di3sel. A perfect answer. Could you, please, also tell me how to change the results order. Now it goes from 1st date of the month to the last, what I need is vice versa. And I cannot get date format back to my old ($result->receive_date)->format('d M, Y')